# Get items from nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list (HashSet actually) of a class that contains 2 other lists. Here's a mockup with example data:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(HashSet<int> a, HashSet<int> b)
    {
        ListA = a;
        ListB = b;
    }

    public HashSet<int> ListA { get; set; }
    public HashSet<int> ListB { get; set; }
}

public class UseCase
{
    public UseCase()
    {
        var hs = new HashSet<Example>();
        hs.Add(new Example(new HashSet<int> { 1}, new HashSet<int> { 100, 200 }));
        hs.Add(new Example(new HashSet<int> { 2,3,4,5 }, new HashSet<int> { 100, 200, 300 }));
        hs.Add(new Example(new HashSet<int> { 6,9,12 }, new HashSet<int> { 200, 300 }));
    }
}
```

Here are the rules for the two lists:

List A contains only unique numbers - they are never repeated, either within their own HashSet or any other ListA HashSet.

List B contains numbers that are unique within their own HashSet, but they may be repeated in one or more List B HashSet.

What I'm trying to do is return all numbers in matching ListA rows, where a specific number exists in ListB.

Here's a mockup linq query:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDistinctFromListA(int b)
{
    return UsesCases
        .Where(x => x.ListB.Contains(b))
}
```

So, at this point I have a number of rows, but I now need to extract all numbers from matching ListB lists. If the parameter entered was 100, then I would expect to return a list containing the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

I've been playing around with All and SelectMany but can't seem to get the result I need.

Comment: what is UseCases?

Comment: `hs.Where(x => x.ListB.Contains(100)).SelectMany(x => x.ListA)` works for me? --> `SelectManyIterator { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`

Comment: @Patrick - it just represents the collection I create - it is a static HashSet<example>, the same as the one in the UseCase Class

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling hashsets "lists".  They're not lists, they're hashsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(HashSet<int> a, HashSet<int> b)
    {
        ListA = a;
        ListB = b;
    }

    public HashSet<int> ListA { get; set; }
    public HashSet<int> ListB { get; set; }
}

static IEnumerable<int> GetDistinctFromListA(HashSet<Example> hs, int b)
{
    var rv = hs.Aggregate(new HashSet<int>(), (acc, el) =>
    {
        if (el.ListB.Contains(b)) acc.UnionWith(el.ListA);
        return acc;
    });

    return rv;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<Example>();
    hs.Add(new Example(new HashSet<int> { 1 }, new HashSet<int> { 100, 200 }));
    hs.Add(new Example(new HashSet<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new HashSet<int> { 100, 200, 300 }));
    hs.Add(new Example(new HashSet<int> { 6, 9, 12 }, new HashSet<int> { 200, 300 }));

    foreach (var b in hs.SelectMany(e => e.ListB).Distinct())
        Console.WriteLine($"{b} => {string.Join(",", GetDistinctFromListA(hs, b))}");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This goes through all Elements of hs, checks each elements ListB if it contains b and if so adds its ListA elements to the result.

If you compare only Hashsets without depending on other Hashsets you can use Intersect / Union / Except etc. (set theory stuff).

Comment: I think this is the right way to do this. Also, I think you're missing a closing `);`

Comment: One more thing. Apparently `HashSet` doesn't have an `AddRange`, but it does have `UnionWith` which will give the correct result

Answer (score 1):

A `HashSet` is meant to contain only unique values and this is to say that all queries you make inherently return distinct values. If you want to find the intersection between two `HashSet` you can call the `Intersect` method.

For example:

```
//The additional 1 is ignored here
HashSet<int> A = new HashSet<int> { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
HashSet<int> B = new HashSet<int> { 1, 5, 8, 9 };
var Result = A.Intersect(B);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return the intersection of 2 sets

There is a Linq function that does this

```
var commonInBoth = List1.Intersect(List2);
```